# Limiting number of Cores using msconfig

Tags: windows, winapi, cpu, processor, cpu-cores

I want to down core machine(PC) using application or driver.

- I've tried using ***msconfig*** ,user can limit number of core he wanted to be enabled.
- When selecting option msconfig -> Boot -> Advanced Option -> Number of processor, drop down list.
- But every processor(Intel , AMD,..etc) having different hardware architecture. Still using **msconfig** , user can able to limit number of cores.

  1. Want to know how **msconfig** is handling this functionality?
  2. Is that tool writing into any **CPU register**?
  3. Or any Windows API to do the same?

Please share your thoughts.

Comment: I do not understand the question.

Comment: @andlabs .you might aware about CPU core limiting using msconfig right?

Comment: Vague and nebulous. What do you actually want to do?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan.. want to down cores using application or driver. and want to understand how msconfig does core controlling..

Comment: @RDX: If you have to ask, you aren't smart enough to understand the consequences. If you need to *"down core"*, use the *msconfig* tool. If you want to automate the process, either use the [BCDEdit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff542205.aspx) tool, or access the [Boot Configuration Data WMI Provider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb986746.aspx).

Comment: @llnspectable.ok.try to understand que before downvote..i've already mention that i know that it can be done using "msconfig"..in question i've mentioned that i want to know how msconfig is writing data in OS or hardware register..

Comment: @RDX: This is a poor question, and I voted on it to convey this. It lacks focus and is inconsistent. The title asks about doing something using a particular tool, and the question asks, how to do it without that tool. It is hard to argue **for** the usefulness of this question. And while you seem to be genuinely surprised, you may consider taking the [tour] to find out, how this site works. Reading through [ask] won't hurt either.

Comment: @llnspectable.. check answer of @ Ari0nhh..in answer, really good explanation given..he/she understood question..so he/she is having better understanding..so please try to understand what somebody wants to say ,instead of judgement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Windows uses `HAL` (Hardware Abstraction Layer), which allows all its components to work the same way with the different hardware. Specifics are handled by the hardware device drivers.
2. CPU registers are used by processor when it is executes a code. There are many kinds of registers, they all are described in the processor developer specification. While msconfig of course using CPU registers, it just a configuration tool. Also you should understand, that each process has its own register state structure called `CONTEXT`, so it is unclear what exactly you are trying to achieve.
3. `msconfig` just saves a configuration information, which is used by Windows kernel, so it could limit CPU cores/memory on initialization. You could limit available processors for the selected process using API function `SetProcessAffinityMask`.

Comment: @Ari0nhh..Thank you for explanation.. Can u please let me know that  "SetProcessAffinityMask"  api can be used to DownCore windows machine? And if yes then please share links or sample code..

Comment: No it could not. It just limits processor cores, which is available to the scheduler for process threads. If you need to limit core count globally, you have to modify BCD (boot configuration data), which exactly msconfig does. Doing that yourself is pretty dangerous and could easily make your system unbootable.

Comment: Ya..that's true..need to handle carefully..but i thought that may be any CPU register or any OS property that having data of number of cores to be disabled..

Comment: May be after doing setting in mscinfig -> Boot options, OS stores that allowed processor count in some hardware or in BCD..not sure on that